# Can SharePoint 2013 and Microsoft Dynamics GP 2013 run on the same server?

Tags: sharepoint, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, ssrs, microsoft-dynamics-gp

We have a new Windows 2012 server with SQL Server 2012 and Microsoft Dynamics GP 2013 running on it. I have been asked to install SharePoint 2013 on this server also. I know GP 2013 now uses SSRS for its reporting and we plan on integrating SSRS with SharePoint 2013 also. Does anyone know if installing SharePoint will cause problems with GP's reporting?

Comment: Oh. My. God.  This may be the worst thing I've heard all year... and I spent the last month or so deploying hundreds of printers.

Comment: If you install the Hyper-V role on it and install multuiple Windows guests and install them separately to each guest (and your hardware is sized to handle the load)

Comment: You can use this as your guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336923/install-crm-2011-and-sharepoint-2010-on-same-machine if you are crazy enough to trust developers.